# Windows Search query does not find all indexed offline files

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search, offline-files

I'm encountering a strange problem with Windows Search and my offline files. I've got a folder on a network share. The folder is made available offline. Among others, it contains these files (there's some more `Hellfrost *` ones):

```
Hellfrost Bestiary.pdf
Hellfrost Calendar PF.pdf
Hellfrost Calendar.pdf
[...]
Hellfrost Players Guide.pdf
[...]
```

### Symptoms

At the Windows 8 startscreen, I type `hellfrost`. Only two results show up:

```
Hellfrost Bestiary.pdf
Hellfrost Calendar PF.pdf
```

However, the other files obviously are indexed as well:

- Searching for `players` finds `Hellfrost Players Guide.pdf`
- Searching for `hellfrost calendar` finds both `Hellfrost Calendar PF.pdf` and `Hellfrost Calendar.pdf`

### What I've tried

- Ran Windows Troubleshooting for Windows Search
- Rebuilt index
- Turned offline files off and on again

Comment: Does `*hellfrost*` make any difference at all?

Comment: No, same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior seems to be by design, and it has nothing to do with offline files.

**When searching "Everywhere" (selected by default), Windows Search apparently displays only two results from each source (apps, settings, files, not sure what else).**

**By choosing "Files" from the dropdown menu above the search box, all expected results appear in the list.**

I confirmed this on a different PC with "standard" (non-offline) files. While I consider this a serious design flaw regarding user experience (there should be something to indicate that not all results are shown), at least now I know how to find all my stuff.